При работе с kafka возникает ошибка
Ошибка:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: fetchMetadata.

Вот мой контроллер:
package controllers;

import kafka.KafkaProducer;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@ComponentScan("kafka")
@RequestMapping
public class KafkaController {
    private final KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;
    @PostMapping("kafka/send")
    public String KafkaSend(@RequestBody String message){
        kafkaProducer.SendMessage(message);
        return "Success";
    }
}

Вот producer :
package kafka;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KafkaProducer {
    private final KafkaTemplate<String , String> kafkaTemplate;
    public void SendMessage(String message){
        kafkaTemplate.send("TestTopic",message);
    }
}

Kafka config:
package kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public NewTopic newTopic(){
        return new NewTopic(
                "TestTopic",1,(short) 1
        );
    }
}

Consumer:
package kafka;

import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumer {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "TestTopic",groupId = "my_consumer")
    public void listen(String message){
        System.out.println("Message - " + message);
    }
}

Stack:
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.4.0)


2025-01-01T09:50:39.175+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    bootstrap.controllers = []
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.metrics.push = true
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.recovery.strategy = none
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2025-01-01T09:50:39.365+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.8.1
2025-01-01T09:50:39.366+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [           main] 
2025-01-01T09:50:40.371+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:40.371+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:41.135+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   dminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:42.234+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:43.105+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:43.106+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:44.087+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:44.088+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:45.181+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:45.181+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] 
2025-01-01T09:50:49.554+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:49.555+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:50.425+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] 
2025-01-01T09:50:51.518+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:51.518+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:52.393+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:52.394+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:53.378+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:53.379+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:54.469+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:54.469+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:55.460+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:55.460+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:56.565+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:56.566+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:57.676+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:57.676+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:58.557+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:58.557+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:50:59.649+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:50:59.650+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:00.741+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:00.742+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:01.838+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:01.838+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:02.938+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:02.939+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:03.922+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:03.923+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:04.910+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:04.910+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:06.002+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:06.003+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:07.095+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:07.095+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:08.081+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:08.082+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.

2025-01-01T09:51:09.382+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager         : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: fetchMetadata

2025-01-01T09:51:09.383+03:00 ERROR 30324 --- [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not configure topics

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Timed out waiting to get existing topics
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$13(KafkaAdmin.java:558) ~[spring-kafka-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1430) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.checkPartitions(KafkaAdmin.java:537) ~[spring-kafka-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.addOrModifyTopicsIfNeeded(KafkaAdmin.java:430) ~[spring-kafka-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.initialize(KafkaAdmin.java:276) ~[spring-kafka-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaAdmin.java:240) ~[spring-kafka-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2139) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-clients-3.8.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$13(KafkaAdmin.java:540) ~[spring-kafka-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

2025-01-01T09:51:10.152+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:10.152+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:11.242+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:11.243+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:12.334+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:12.334+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:13.205+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:13.205+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:14.188+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:14.188+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:15.061+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:15.062+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:16.163+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:16.163+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:17.254+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:17.255+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:18.130+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:18.131+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:19.004+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:19.005+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:19.396+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Forcing a hard I/O thread shutdown. Requests in progress will be aborted.
2025-01-01T09:51:19.397+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered
2025-01-01T09:51:19.398+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager         : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: fetchMetadata

2025-01-01T09:51:19.398+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Timed out 2 remaining operation(s) during close.
2025-01-01T09:51:19.402+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics scheduler closed
2025-01-01T09:51:19.402+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2025-01-01T09:51:19.403+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics reporters closed
2025-01-01T09:51:19.417+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 4044 (http) with context path '/'
2025-01-01T09:51:19.426+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [           main] r.s.StudentsApp.StudentsAppApplication   : Started StudentsAppApplication in 43.116 seconds (process running for 43.513)
2025-01-01T09:51:48.064+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [nio-4044-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2025-01-01T09:51:48.065+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [nio-4044-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2025-01-01T09:51:48.065+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [nio-4044-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2025-01-01T09:51:48.127+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [nio-4044-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.gzip.level = -1
    compression.lz4.level = 9
    compression.type = none
    compression.zstd.level = 3
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = true
    enable.metrics.push = true
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metadata.recovery.strategy = none
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true
    partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 0
    partitioner.class = null
    partitioner.ignore.keys = false
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

2025-01-01T09:51:48.148+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [nio-4044-exec-1] o.a.k.c.t.i.KafkaMetricsCollector        : initializing Kafka metrics collector
2025-01-01T09:51:48.158+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [nio-4044-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2025-01-01T09:51:48.178+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [nio-4044-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.8.1
2025-01-01T09:51:48.178+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [nio-4044-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 70d6ff42debf7e17
2025-01-01T09:51:48.178+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [nio-4044-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1735714308178
2025-01-01T09:51:48.374+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:48.375+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.


(localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:48.477+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2025-01-01T09:51:48.630+03:00  INFO 30324 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2025-01-01T09:51:48.631+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
2025-01-01T09:51:48.631+03:00  WARN 30324 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected


как задать хороший вопрос. начните с внесения осмысленности в заголовок вопроса. в данный момент заголовок не несёт в себе никакой полезной для ответа информации

Полный стэктрейс ошибки?

где и как поднимаете Кафку, локально или в каком-то облаке?
